# How do you compare decendants that are on multiple levels

Tags: c#, visual-studio, attributes, linq-to-xml

I am currently working with XML files in which i must retrieve nodes under a particular element. These nodes mostly contain `DateTime` objects and when they are retrieved they get updated. The problem is one of the attributes is two levels lower than the rest (causing the need for a second `.Descendants`). How can I compare the attribute that is two levels lower (`_StartDate`) with one of the attributes that isn't. I'm specifically looking to compare `_StartDate` with `_AccountReportedDate`.

```
var creditLiabilities = xDoc.Descendants("CREDIT_LIABILITY").Descendants("_PAYMENT_PATTERN")
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Element = x,
                        AccountOpenedDate = x.Attribute("_AccountOpenedDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountOpenedDate").Value + "-01",
                        AccountClosedDate = x.Attribute("_AccountClosedDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountClosedDate").Value + "-01",
                        AccountPaidDate = x.Attribute("_AccountPaidDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountPaidDate").Value + "-01",
                        AccountReportedDate = x.Attribute("_AccountReportedDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountReportedDate").Value + "-01",
                        LastActivityDate = x.Attribute("_LastActivityDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_LastActivityDate").Value + "-01",
                        AccountStatusDate = x.Attribute("_AccountStatusDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountStatusDate").Value + "-01",
                        Monthcount = x.Attribute("_MonthsReviewedCount") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_MonthsReviewedCount").Value,
                        StartDate = x.Attribute("_StartDate") == null ? string.Empty :x.Attribute("_StartDate").Value,
                    }
               );
```

Below is the XML code:

```
<CREDIT_LIABILITY CreditLiabilityID="CreditLiabilityID_52885" x_MasterTradelineId="52885" x_CDOTradelineId="153216" BorrowerID="Borrower" CreditFileID="CreditFileId_14462 CreditFileId_14460 CreditFileId_14461" x_TradelineGroupId="152665" x_Primary="Y" x_BureauName="Experian" x_SubscriberCode="1631440" _AccountIdentifier="7634134580" _AccountOpenedDate="2014-04" _AccountOwnershipType="Individual" _AccountReportedDate="2014-11" _AccountStatusDate="2015-01" _AccountStatusType="Open" x_FannieAccountStatusType="Open" x_StatusLong="Current account/was 30 days past due date" _AccountType="Installment" _ConsumerDisputeIndicator="N" _DerogatoryDataIndicator="N" _HighBalanceAmount="21811.00" _LastActivityDate="2014-09" _ManualUpdateIndicator="N" x_ActualPaymentAmount="363.00" _MonthsReviewedCount="8" _TermsMonthsCount="60" _UnpaidBalanceAmount="19993.00" x_UnpaidBalanceNumber="19993.0000" CreditLoanType="CreditCard" x_FNMACreditLoanCode="CC" x_RealEstateRelated="0" x_PrimaryRealEstate="0" x_ECOA2="B" x_CREDITOR_Name="FORD CRED" x_PrimaryGroupBy="Installment" _MonthlyPaymentAmount="363.00" _TermsSourceType="Provided" x_EstPayment="N" x_EstPaymentPct="0.020" _MonthsRemainingCount="53">
      <_CREDITOR _Name="FORD CRED" />
      <_CURRENT_RATING _Code="C" _Type="Late30Days" />
      <_LATE_COUNT _30Days="1" _60Days="0" _90Days="0" x_30Lates="07/14" x_60Lates="" x_90Lates="" />
      <_PAYMENT_PATTERN _Data="CCC1CC" _StartDate="2014-11" />
      <CREDIT_REPOSITORY _SourceType="TransUnion" x_Primary="No" _SubscriberCode="03796761" x_CDOTradelineId="153213" />
      <CREDIT_REPOSITORY _SourceType="Equifax" x_Primary="No" _SubscriberCode="644FA04640" x_CDOTradelineId="153215" />
      <CREDIT_REPOSITORY _SourceType="Experian" x_Primary="Yes" _SubscriberCode="1631440" x_CDOTradelineId="153216" />
    </CREDIT_LIABILITY>
```

Comment: Most of the attributes you're looking for aren't in `<_PAYMENT_PATTERN>` anyway - and it's not at all clear what kind of comparison you're looking for, given that you're just creating an instance of an anonymous type. I suspect it would be best to have one property for the `_AccountReportedDate` attribute in `CREDIT_LIABILITY` and one for the `_StartDate` attribute in `_PAYMENT_PATTERN`. It's not clear what you mean about being *two* levels lower, btw - the element is a direct child.(If you can change the XML format here at all, I would do so, by the way. All those underscores are horrible...)

Comment: I am looking to compare the dates. If _StartDate does not equal _AccountReportedDate, it will set the value to _AccountReportedDate date. Also would this idea work when there are multiple CREDIT_LIABILITIES. As for format i am not allowed to change anything

Comment: Well assuming you want to create one object per `CREDIT_LIABILITY` that should be fine. But I would *strongly* recommend not doing the comparison in the projection. Instead, create an object with both of the properties you're interested in, in a simple way, then perform the comparison between those property values separately.

Comment: Like this?
  var paymentpatterns = xDoc.Descendants("CREDIT_LIABILITY").DescendantsAndSelf("PAYMENT_PATTERN")
                                  .Select(x => new
                                  {
                                      Element = x,
                                      AccountReportedDate = x.Attribute("_AccountReportedDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_AccountReportedDate").Value,
                                      StartDate = x.Attribute("_StartDate") == null ? string.Empty : x.Attribute("_StartDate").Value
                                  });

Comment: I didn't suggest one *just* for those two. I'm just saying you should have those two properties as part of your anonymous type.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `DescendantsAndSelf`. Just use `Descendants`, and then use `StartDate = (string) x.Element("_PAYMENT_PATTERN").Attribute("_StartDate")`.

Comment: Good Morning. Sorry to bother you again but i have one more question. I have the elements retrieved and updated correctly (based on my debugging) but how do i write the start date back to the xml file. Currently they are in a foreach loop foreach(var tradeline in creditLiabilities) and the code for updating other values looks like this tradeLine.Element.Attribute("_AccountOpenedDate").Value = NewDate.ToString("yyyy-MM");

Comment: If you have another question, you should ask it in another post... ideally one which is clear, with a short but complete example. Stack Overflow is *not* designed for ongoing support like this.